# Найти и выделить слово в <textarea>

Tags: javascript

Я хочу написать функцию выделения определённого слова в textarea, но не знаю как можно найти координаты этого слова, подскажите пожалуйста выход из ситуации?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findSelectTxt(text) {
    var input = document.getElementById ("myText");
    // Координаты начала и конца выделения 'text'
    input.selectionStart = 6;
    input.selectionEnd = 15;
    input.focus ();
}
</script>
<textarea id="myText">здесь некоторый текст</textarea>
<button onclick="findSelectTxt('некоторый')">Найти и выделить</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

с помощью [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) находим индекс начала строки, а индекс конца искомой строки получаем так: `длина искомой строки (кол-во символов) + позиция первого символа искомой строки`

```js
function findSelectTxt(text) {
    var input = document.getElementById ("myText");
    // Координаты начала и конца выделения 'text'
    input.selectionStart = input.value.indexOf(text);
    input.selectionEnd = input.value.indexOf(text) + text.length;
    input.focus ();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myText">здесь некоторый текст</textarea>
<button onclick="findSelectTxt('здесь')">Найти и выделить здесь</button>
<button onclick="findSelectTxt('некоторый')">Найти и выделить некоторый</button>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо вам большое! А то я уже всю голову сломал :-)